# IPv6 / Kea DHCP / Ubuntu 20.04 / DNS Server Issue

Tags: domain-name-system, dhcp, ipv6, ubuntu-20.04

Here is my current setup:

I have IPv6 / IPv4 enabled in my environment.

My router is doing RA for that IPv6 subnet.

Router is configured with other options flag.

I have Kea DHCP6 / DHCP4 server enabled.

Kea dhcp6 server has options config set with dns-server and other related parameters set.

I have Ubuntu machine that I have IPv4 DHCP enabled and its also receiving RA for IPv6.

When IPv4 is configured I'm only seeing v4 DNS servers in resolvectl under "Current DNS Server" and "DNS Servers" and DNS resolution works.

When IPv4 is disabled and only IPv6 RA are working I see only IPv6 "DNS Server" section populated and DNS resolution does NOT work.

This is causing DNS resolution to stop working since Current DNS Server in resolvectl is not showing up.

What could cause Current DNS Server not to show v6 address?

Update Below:
Below is my Kea DHCP6 config.

```
{
"Dhcp6": {
    "interfaces-config": {
        "interfaces": ["ens3"]
    },
            "option-data": [{
                "name": "dns-servers",
                "data": "<V6 DNS IP ADDRESS>",
                "code": 23
            }]
}}
```

V6 host DNS is passed via DHCP6 and RA is just passing other config options in order to let the host know to look for DNS via DHCP6.

I did packet capture and I can see RA packet with other config flag set. The host gets the DNS address as I can see it in resolvectl under DNS Servers section, but host doesn't resolve DNS.

Thanks,

Comment: Please edit your question to add details. What is the Kea dhcp6 config file? How is the host configured for DNS? As it sounds like systemd,  a `systemctl cat`  of the .network unit in question may help.  Also do a packet capture while the host network comes up, find the DHCPv6 and RA RDNSS for the DNS config on the wire.

Comment: See my updates above to some of the questions you have. I've added Kea v6 DHCP config and as you can see its pretty simple setup since I have RA handling rest of it.